# Splitting a dataframe column on a pattern of characters and numerals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that is:

```
    A
1   king, crab, 2008
2   green, 2010
3   blue
4   green no. 4
5   green, house
```

I want to split the dates out into:

```
    A                  B
1   king, crab         2008
2   green              2010
3   blue
4   green no. 4
5   green, house
```

I cant split the first instance of ", " because that would make:

```
    A                  B
1   king               crab, 2008
2   green              2010
3   blue
4   green no. 4
5   green              house
```

I cant split after the last instance of ", " because that would make:

```
    A                  B
1   king crab          2008
2   green              2010
3   blue
4   green no. 4
5   green              house
```

I also cant separate it by numbers because that would make:

```
    A                  B
1   king, crab         2008
2   green              2010
3   blue
4   green no.          4
5   green, house
```

Is there some way to split by ", " and then a 4 digit number that is between two values? The two values condition would be extra safety to filter out accidental 4 digit numbers that are clearly not years. For example.

Split by: 
`", " + (four digit number between 1000 - 2021)`

Also appreciated are answers that split by:
`", " + four digit number`

Even better would be an answer that took into account that the number is ALWAYS at the end of the string.

Comment: Could you split the last element after the comma? `split(",")[-1]` or will that not work in every case?

Comment: No because there could theoretically be something like "green, house". Sorry I will add that to the question.

Comment: Do you actually need to split? Or do you just need to extract the four digit number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can just use `series.str.extract` and `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["king, crab, 2008","green, 2010","blue","green no. 4","green, house"]})

df["year"] = df["A"].str.extract("(\d{4})")
df["A"] = df["A"].str.replace(",\s\d{4}","")

print (df)

              A  year
0    king, crab  2008
1         green  2010
2          blue   NaN
3   green no. 4   NaN
4  green, house   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

list_dict_Input = [{'A': 'king, crab, 2008'}, 
                   {'A':  'green, 2010'}, 
                   {'A':  'green no. 4'}, 
                   {'A':   'green no. 4'},]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict_Input)

for row_Index in range(len(df)):
    text = (df.iloc[row_Index]['A']).strip()
    last_4_Char = (text[-4:])

    if last_4_Char.isdigit() and int(last_4_Char) >= 1000 and  int(last_4_Char) <= 2021:
            df.at[row_Index, 'B'] = last_4_Char


print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin. I added: new.at[row_Index, 'A'] = text[:-6] as well to remove the dates and comma.